# Spring. @Scheduled совместно с @Transactional

Tags: spring, планировщик-задач, transaction, транзакции, schedule

Подскажите, правильно ли использовать аннотации @Scheduled и @Transactional у одного метода? Или их стоит разделять на разные методы/классы?

Пример 1. При использовании двух методов, в случае ошибки транзакции (к примеру несоответствие версий записей в БД при Оптимистичной блокировке), `methodB` ловит исключение, как и должно быть.

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void methodB() {
    try {
        // Обновление записи в БД
        this.methodDAO.update(myObj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("Error catch");
    }
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000 * 60)
public void methodA() {
    methodB();
}
```

Пример 2. Один метод для двух аннотаций. В случае ошибки транзакции, исключение не ловится, а отображается сразу в Stacktrace.

```
@Transactional
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000 * 60)
@Override
public void methodB() {
    try {
        // Обновление записи в БД
        this.methodDAO.update(myObj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("Error catch");
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

---

```
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.wrapStaleStateException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:212) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1411) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3168) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2382) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
```